# Problem installing erlang version 23.2 on kali linux using asdf

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, kali-linux, asdf

```
asdf install erlang
Downloading kerl...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 85117  100 85117    0     0   182k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  182k
asdf_23.2 is not a kerl-managed Erlang/OTP installation
No build named asdf_23.2
Downloading 23.2 to /home/reddy/.asdf/downloads/erlang/23.2...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100 94.6M  100 94.6M    0     0  60.9M      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 84.7M
Extracting source code
Building Erlang/OTP 23.2 (asdf_23.2), please wait...
APPLICATIONS INFORMATION (See: /home/reddy/.asdf/plugins/erlang/kerl-home/builds/asdf_23.2/otp_build_23.2.log)
 * wx             : wxWidgets was not compiled with --enable-compat28, wx will NOT be useable
 * Can not link the wx driver, wx will NOT be useable

Build failed.
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
gmake[4]: *** [x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/Makefile:179: ../priv/obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/pkey.o] Error 1
gmake[4]: Leaving directory '/home/reddy/.asdf/plugins/erlang/kerl-home/builds/asdf_23.2/otp_src_23.2/lib/crypto/c_src'
gmake[3]: *** [/home/reddy/.asdf/plugins/erlang/kerl-home/builds/asdf_23.2/otp_src_23.2/make/run_make.mk:35: opt] Error 2
gmake[3]: Leaving directory '/home/reddy/.asdf/plugins/erlang/kerl-home/builds/asdf_23.2/otp_src_23.2/lib/crypto/c_src'
gmake[2]: *** [/home/reddy/.asdf/plugins/erlang/kerl-home/builds/asdf_23.2/otp_src_23.2/make/otp_subdir.mk:29: opt] Error 2
gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/home/reddy/.asdf/plugins/erlang/kerl-home/builds/asdf_23.2/otp_src_23.2/lib/crypto'
gmake[1]: *** [/home/reddy/.asdf/plugins/erlang/kerl-home/builds/asdf_23.2/otp_src_23.2/make/otp_subdir.mk:29: opt] Error 2
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/reddy/.asdf/plugins/erlang/kerl-home/builds/asdf_23.2/otp_src_23.2/lib'
gmake: *** [Makefile:505: libs] Error 2

Please see /home/reddy/.asdf/plugins/erlang/kerl-home/builds/asdf_23.2/otp_build_23.2.log for full details.
Removing all artifacts except the logfile
(Use KERL_AUTOCLEAN=0 to keep build on failure, if desired)
Cleaning up compilation products for asdf_23.2
Cleaned up compilation products for asdf_23.2 under /home/reddy/.asdf/plugins/erlang/kerl-home/builds
```

I already have version mentioned in the .tool-versions. When I am trying to install erlang version, I am getting the following errors. I have installed all the required dependencies. How to resolve it?

Comment: Are there any relevant error messages in `/home/reddy/.asdf/plugins/erlang/kerl-home/builds/asdf_23.2/otp_build_23.2.log`?

Answer (score 2):

It got resolved after doing this:

```
git clone https://github.com/openssl/openssl.git --branch OpenSSL_1_0_2-stable  
./config --prefix=\$HOME/.openssl-1.0 shared -fPIC  
make depend && make && make install  
mkdir -p \$HOME/.openssl-1.0  
cd \$HOME/.openssl.1-0  
ln -sf /usr/lib/openssl-1.0 lib  
ln -sf /usr/include/openssl-1.0 include  
KERL_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS="--without-javac --disable-debug --with-ssl=\$HOME/.openssl-1.0" \ asdf install erlang 23.2
```